# Is there an accepted way of dealing with events containing ID of another aggregate?

Tags: domain-driven-design, event-sourcing, eventstoredb

Lets say an Invoice was generated for a Customer. This specific event would look something like this:

```
invoice.raised {
   "id": "4dbcff82-6f35-4155-9aec-f8185c1f932f",
   "total": "50.00",
   "description": "Order 01133",
   "customer_id": "c2206843-414d-454f-9894-57c6b11b9c00"
}
```

This is fairly simple example and it refers to customer aggregate that an invoice belongs to.

Difficulty manifests itself when I want to create Invoices view and I want to embed Customer's name in an invoice. I could do two things - enrich the original event to contain Customer's name or load up the Customers view to find out what the name is when I am building my Invoices view. 
Now this is not a very complicated example, but in some cases it becomes almost unmanageable to enrich events anymore as I end up with a lot of properties of various aggregates copied into the event that is very specific to some other aggregate.

Is there a universally accepted way of dealing with this apart from enriching events? Because everytime now the invoice.cancelled event is raised I will have to also include the amount of the invoice once again, so that I can update Customers view with new balance for instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> in some cases it becomes almost unmanageable to enrich events anymore as I end up with a lot of properties of various aggregates copied into the event that is very specific to some other aggregate.

That's right, it makes your events less manageable.

So **I'd say that it's enough to have just `customer_id` and ask for customer name when you build your read model**:

- It can be at projecting time, when denormalised view is built.
- It can be at querying time, when resulted view model is built based on invoices and customers (for this use case you can have dedicated list of customers with `customer_id` and `customer_name` only)

> Because everytime now the `invoice.cancelled` event is raised I will have to also include the `amount` of the invoice once again, so that I can update Customers view with new balance for instance.

`invoice.cancelled` event is triggered by Invoice aggregate root, I expect, and it owns `amount` so it is natural to put `amount` into `invoice.cancelled` event.

`invoice.raised` event is triggered by Invoice aggregate root too but it does not own customer name. It cannot check if customer name is consistent at specific point in time anyway. That's why instead of embedding customer name you can simly query it when you build your read model.

BTW there is a good reading about designing events - [6 Code Smells with your CQRS Events – and How to Avoid Them](http://danielwhittaker.me/2014/10/18/6-code-smells-cqrs-events-avoid/)

Answer (score 1):

> Difficulty manifests itself when I want to create Invoices view and I want to embed Customer's name in an invoice.
>
> Is there a universally accepted way of dealing with this apart from enriching events?

You don't want to go down the road of enriching events if you can possibly help it -- that increases the coupling in your implementation, which makes changing your model more expensive.

UI Composition techniques might guide you in a useful direction.  Udi Dahan wrote about them a number of times.  Some examples

- [UI Composition Techniques...](http://udidahan.com/2012/06/23/ui-composition-techniques-for-correct-service-boundaries/)
- [Secret of Better UI Composition](http://particular.net/blog/secret-of-better-ui-composition)

The basic plot - instead of InvoiceView fetching Customer state, and using that state to produce a view of the customer, instead the InvoiceView delegates a share of the responsibility to the Customer component itself

```
InvoiceView (e : invoice.raised) {
    InvoiceWidget(e.id)
    CustomerWidget(e.customer_id)
}
```